# ContentResolver where clause on two columns

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, android-contentprovider

I implemented a ContentProvider in which the SQLlite table has the following columns:

- id: INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT
- parentId: INTEGER NOT NULL (foreign key)
- name: TEXT
- archived: INTEGER

The 'archived' column is actually used as a boolean flag where 0 is "no" and 1 is "yes, it's archived". On that data I'm doing two different queries.

1. give me all elements that belong to a specific parent (parentId = xxx)
2. give me all elements that belong to a specific parent and are not archived (parentId = xxx AND archived = 0)

   public Cursor getElements(int parentId, boolean includeArchived) {

   ```
   Uri queryUri = MyContentProvider.CONTENT_URI;
   String[] projection = new String[] { "id", "parentId", "name", "archived" };
   ContentResolver cr = mContext.getContentResolver();

   String where = null;
   String[] whereValues = null;

   if (!includeArchived) {
       where = "parentId = ? AND archived = ?";
       whereValues = new String[] { Integer.toString(parentId), "0" };
   } else {
       where = "parentId = ?";
       whereValues = new String[] { Integer.toString(parentId) };
   }

   return cr.query(queryUri, projection, where, whereValues, null);
   ```

   }

The query that does not care about the archived-flag works, but the other one delivers no results even though the values for archived are 0 in the database. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Archived is declared as INTEGER, but you seem to use `"0"` which corresponds to a string

Comment: Where clause and values must be specified as String. That's because of the the ContentResolver.query method is declared like that. And Integer.toString(parentId) does work perfectly. But the second where does not. Even if I use Integer.toString(0)

Comment: I found the problem. I had no default value on the archived column. Solution is either set default values like INTEGER DEFAULT 0 or set the integer value correctly (so it's not null) when inserting new rows.